Can the Square Root of a Prime Element of an Integral Domain Ever Belong to Its Field of Fractions?
I am trying to come up with an integral domain $R$, containing some prime element $p$, such that the field of fractions $F$ of $R$ contains a square root of $p$. This is straightforward if we replace the primality condition with irreducibility. Just consider the ring $K[t^2,t^3]\subset K[t]$ where $K$ is any field. Then $t^2$ is irreducible and the square root $\frac{t^3}{t^2}$ is in the field of fractions.
$t^2$, however, is not prime, since $t^3t^3$ is in the ideal $(t^2)$ without $t^3$ being in said ideal. Either way, the ring $R$ we're looking for cannot be an integrally closed domain, since a square root of $p$ is the root of a monic polynomial over $R$. Therefore $R$ cannot be a UFD, PID, or any other of those well-behaved types of rings.
Since the integral closure of $R$ in $F$ is the intersection of all valuation rings containing $R$, my problem can be restated as finding an integral domain $R$ with some prime element $p$ such that every valuation ring containing $R$ has a square root of $p$.
We must find $p,a,b\in R$ with $p$ prime and $a^2=b^2p$. From this it follows that $a^2\in (p)$ and, by primality, $a=a'p$ for some new $a'\in R$, so we can write $a'^2p^2=b^2p$, cancel to $a'^2p=b^2$, and then $b^2$ is in (p) and as above $b=b'p$ for some $b'\in R$. Repeating the process, we can keep factoring $p$ out of both $a$ and $b$ infinitely many times. In other words, any elements $a,b$ such that $a/b$ is a square root of $p$ will both have to be infinitely divisible by $p$. We are therefore looking for a non-Noetherian ring in which Krull's principal ideal theorem fails, since the ideal $(p)$ must have infinite height.
It looks to me like an integral domain with a prime satisfying our property must be somewhat pathological. On the other hand, I have also made no progress when trying to prove such a ring cannot exist. Does anyone know if this is the case? Thank you all for your help!

What about the $k$-subalgebra of the field $Q(k[a,b,p]/(a^2- b^2 p)) = k(b,p)[a]/(a^2-b^2 p)$ generated by $p$ and all the $a/p^s$, $b/p^s$? (Just as an idea, I didn't check if $p$ is a prime here.)

We can take the subring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]$ generated by the $y/2^n$ and the $\sqrt{2} \cdot y/2^n$ for $n \geq 0$. This is obviously an integral domain containing the elements $y$ and $\sqrt{2} \cdot y$, so that $\sqrt{2}$ lies in its field of fractions. With this definition of the ring, though, it is not so easy to see that $2$ is a prime element. Therefore, let me define this ring differently.
Define a commutative ring by generators and relations by
$$R := \mathbb{Z}[x_0,x_1,\dotsc;y_0,y_1,\dotsc]/(x_n = 2 x_{n+1}, \, y_n = 2 y_{n+1}, \, x_n^2 = 2 y_n^2).$$
Then $2 \in R$ is a prime element since $2 \neq 0$ (see below) and $R/(2) = \mathbb{F}_2[x_0,\dotsc;y_0,\dotsc]/(x_n=0, \, y_n=0) = \mathbb{F}_2$. We also have the equation $x_0^2 = 2 y_n^2$ in $R$. So it only remains to prove that $R$ is an integral domain, and that $y_0 \neq 0$.
Define the homomorphism
$$\varphi : R \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y], \quad x_n \mapsto \sqrt{2} \cdot y / 2^n , ~ y_n \mapsto y / 2^n.$$
This is well-defined since the images indeed satisfy the relations in the definition of $R$. It follows immediately that $y_0 \neq 0$ and $2 \neq 0$ in $R$. I claim that $\varphi$ is injective, so that $R$ is an integral domain. It follows also that $R$ is isomorphic to the concrete ring in the first paragraph.
First, consider the ring $S := \mathbb{Z}[y_0,y_1,\dotsc]/(y_n = 2 y_{n+1})$. Here, every monomial can be reduced to a power of some variable, and we can make this variable as high as we want. This implies that every element of this ring has the form $p(y_n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$. You can also see this by regarding $S$ as the filtered colimit of the rings $\mathbb{Z}[y_n]$ with transition maps $\mathbb{Z}[y_n] \to \mathbb{Z}[y_{n+1}]$, $y_n \mapsto 2 y_{n+1}$.
Now, the ring $R$ is isomorphic to $S[x_0,x_1,\dotsc]/(x_n = 2 x_{n+1}, \, x_n^2 = 2 y_n^2)$. Following the same argument as above and using that $x_n^2 \in S$, we conclude that every element of $R$ has the form $s + s' x_k$ for $s,s' \in S$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, elements $u \in R$ have the form
$$u = p(y_n) + q(y_m) x_k$$
with $p,q  \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$ and $n,m,k \in \mathbb{N}$. Now assume that $\varphi(u)=0$. This means
$$0 = p(y/2^n) + q(y/2^m) \sqrt{2} \, y/2^k$$
holds in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y] = \mathbb{Q}[y][\sqrt{2}]$. Since $1,\sqrt{2}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}[y]$, we get $p(y/2^n)=0$ and $q(y/2^m) y/2^k = 0$ in $\mathbb{Q}[y]$. But then $p = 0$ and $q = 0$, and therefore $u = 0$. This finishes the proof that $\varphi$ is injective.
The same construction works more generally. Let $A$ be a factorial ring and $p \in A$ be a prime element. Then in the commutative $A$-algebra $Q(A)(\sqrt{p})[y]$ we can take the $A$-subalgebra $A'$ generated by the $y/p^n$ and the $\sqrt{p} \cdot y/p^n$. Then $A'$ is an integral domain in which $p$ is still a prime element (this is the tricky part) and $Q(A')$ contains $\sqrt{p}$. It should also work with $\sqrt[m]{p}$ for any $m \geq 2$.

Thank you for your response! I'm pretty confident this example is right but I'm confused about parts of the proof:
"every element of this ring has the form $z\cdot y_n^k$ for some $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$."
How about $y_0+y_0^2$? I'm having trouble passing from accepting monomials can be represented in this way to the case of a general element of the ring.

That's true. I have fixed the proof. Please check again.
